# SSL connection and PKIX EROR

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, cryptography, x509

I have two linux as server, one server have software use ldap(have tomcat) and another server have ldap(ldap servr), I want to have ssl connection between ldap server and another server, for do it I generate root certificate and child for root certificate(this certificate common name and Subject Alternative name is Ip add) and I create trust store with java keytool(with root certificate). I put root certificate and server certificate and key from server in ldap config and put trust store in tomcat after running software with tomcat I have this error. How to fix them?

```
 ption: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.startHandshake(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:344)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:208)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:161)
            at ir.cto.crypto.manager.LdapConnector.init2(LdapConnector.java:72)
            at ir.cto.crypto.manager.RepositoryManager.repositoryInit(RepositoryManager.java:192)
            at ir.cto.ca.server.common.ldap.LdapManagerImpl.unPublishCRL(LdapManagerImpl.java:37)
            at ir.cto.ca.server.scheduling.CRLPublishingJob.executeInternal(CRLPublishingJob.java:282)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:66)
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:509)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
            at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1188)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
            at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
            ... 23 more
    Eroor in negotiate
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.startHandshake(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:344)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:208)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:161)
            at ir.cto.crypto.manager.LdapConnector.init2(LdapConnector.java:72)
            at ir.cto.crypto.manager.RepositoryManager.repositoryInit(RepositoryManager.java:192)
            at ir.cto.ca.server.common.ldap.LdapManagerImpl.unPublishCRL(LdapManagerImpl.java:37)
            at ir.cto.ca.server.scheduling.CRLPublishingJob.executeInternal(CRLPublishingJob.java:282)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:66)
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:509)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
            at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1188)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
            at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
            ... 23 more
Eroor in negotiate                         
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.startHandshake(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:344)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:208)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:161)
            at ir.cto.crypto.manager.LdapConnector.init2(LdapConnector.java:72)
            at ir.cto.crypto.manager.RepositoryManager.repositoryInit(RepositoryManager.java:192)
            at ir.cto.ca.server.common.ldap.LdapManagerImpl.unPublishCRL(LdapManagerImpl.java:37)
            at ir.cto.ca.server.scheduling.CRLPublishingJob.executeInternal(CRLPublishingJob.java:282)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:66)
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:509)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
            at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1188)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
            at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
            ... 23 more
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information about your setup. How is Tomcat configured to use SSL? How is LDAP configured to use SSL? Can you connect via SSL to LDAP using something other than Tomcat?

Comment: Tnx, in my ldap I have ssl connection, but in server to connect ldap I have this error in tomcat,

Comment: I create war file in my software and put the webapp in tomcat and .ts file (is trust store) put the web inf my software in tomcat

Comment: What about my third question? Can you connect to your LDAP server using LDAPS with a normal client (i.e. not Tomcat?). It would be helpful to rule out that there's no issue with your LDAP server's configuration.

Comment: hi, I have to pc, in one pc have openldap that connect them with ldap browser in ldaps. in another pc i have software use ldap and it run in tomcat in this pc I put trust store ldap(.ts file have root certificat of ldap) in tomcat and if run this software Have above error.